# iterate 3 dictionaries at the same time by IEnumerator and GetEnumerator from C# VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ienumerator

I need to iterate 3 dictionaries together from C# VS2013.

```
  // got error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double,double>.Enumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double,double>>'
  using (IEnumerator<Dictionary<double,double>> iterator1 = dict1.GetEnumerator())  
  using (IEnumerator<Dictionary<double,double>> iterator2 = dict2.GetEnumerator())
  using (IEnumerator<Dictionary<double,double>> iterator3 = dict3.GetEnumerator())
  while (iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext() && iterator3.MoveNext())
  {
      iterator1.Current. // I need to access key and values of dict1 here. Why none of them can be accessed here  ?

  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enumerator for a `Dictionary<K,V>` will implement `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`.

But this is really a case where `var` makes things much easier:

```
using (var iterator1 = dict1.GetEnumerator())  
using (var iterator2 = dict2.GetEnumerator())
using (var iterator3 = dict3.GetEnumerator())
…
```

Hovering the mouse over the `var` in Visual Studio will tell you the inferred type, you only need to specify the type if you need to override that inference (in this case it is likely to be the helper type `Dictionary<T,V>` uses to implement `IEnumerator<…>`).